# Turning Function With Yield Into One-Liner in Python

Tags: python, while-loop, iterator, generator

I have the following function, which produces a sequence of numbers. I would like to turn it into a one-liner in the form of an iterator or a generator. How can I do that?

```
def one_line_generator():
    sum = 0
    string = "Hello"
    i = 0
    while True:
        sum += ord(string[i])
        yield sum
        if i<len(string)-1:
            i += 1
        else:
            i = 0
```

Comment: Why do you want a one-liner? Deliberate obfuscation is never helpful. Also, don't shadow *sum()*

Comment: @OldBill It is a code-golfy thing :/ Perhaps a borderline for this forum.

Comment: @OldBill In this case though, the one-liner from Nikolay Zakirov makes the intent of the code a lot clearer than the original.

Comment: @blhsing The original could also be written more clearly without it being an one-liner, e.g. `for i in count(): sum += ord(string[i % len(string)]; yield sum`

Answer (score 3):

Another try

```
from itertools import accumulate, cycle
from operator import add
string = "Hello" 
res = accumulate(cycle(map(ord, string)), add)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like so, for instance, if you insist.

```
import itertools

def oneline2(string, i=0):
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(((i := i + ord(c)) for c in s) for s in itertools.repeat(string))
```